# QT image display is not working without declaring openCV namedWindow in windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, user-interface

I am using windows 10 with QT 5.14 opencv 4.20 with contrib version.

I am displaying the image captured by webcam to QT label. It was working perfect in Ubuntu but after migrating to windows it is not working. It work only if I create openCV namedWindow("frame",0). It creates extra window of openCV. I installed openCV 4.20 with_FFMPEG open checked.

I am not able to find the reason? If I tried to make namedWindow() hidden or invisible but there is no option for that. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Here is the code. If I comment the  imshow( "Frame", frame ); its not working and uncommenting this line works but it opens two windows .... Any help will be highly appreciated.

I tried with many installations of openCV with FFMPEG on and off and GStreamer on and off, adding #define  NO_DSHOW_STRSAFE in cap_dshow.cpp file but not getting any solution.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()){
      cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;

    }

    while(1){

      Mat frame;
      cap >> frame;
      if (frame.empty())
        break;

//      imshow( "Frame", frame );

      ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));

      char c=(char)waitKey(25);
      if(c==27)
        break;
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();

}

Regards
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing so that other can benefit if they face same issue.

The problem is solved by adding

`qApp->processEvents();` after the

`ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()));`

Actually what this  `qApp->processEvents();` does is it processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the specified flags until there are no more events to process.

You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy performing a long operation